# Использование слотов/сигналов в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, события, сигналы-слоты

Хочу научиться использовать слоты в Qt, но не могу нормально понять  концепцию их создания. Я читал книгу Макса Шлее, но я так и не понял, что к чему.
Подскажите какой-нибудь мануал по данной теме. Искал в интернете, но так ничего адекватного не нашёл - ни в рунете, ни в англоязычных источниках.

Comment: что значит концепцию их создания? вас интересует как реализован механизм сигналов/слотов qt на с++?

Comment: работу механизма не надо, в вот создание собственных слотов - надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд - вполне подходящие для новичка руководства, в которых не используется пример из официальной документации.

1. https://habr.com/post/141983/
2. https://evileg.com/ru/post/87/